# RxJava for Animations in Android

Tags: android, functional-programming, rx-java, rx-android

I'm trying to use RxJava to animate a view in Android. I need to change the view's Y position on a interval, but it's not working properly. Here's the function I start:

```
private void initiateCurrentWordFall(){
    txtFalling.setY(fallingWordStartY);
    Observable<Long> observable = Observable.interval(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

    fallingSubs = observable
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
            .observeOn(Schedulers.computation())
            .subscribe(new Observer<Long>() {

                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(Long aLong) {
                    if(txtFalling.getY()!=screenHeight) {
                        txtFalling.setY(txtFalling.getY() + 1);
                        Log.d("Txt Y", String.valueOf(txtFalling.getY()));
                    }
                    else
                        wrongAnswerOrWordFeel();
                }
            });
}
```

screenHeight is equal to 1776 in my execution.

This code was supposed to decrement the view's Y by 1 pixel every 0.1 second. I even try to log what's happening, and this is what I get:

```
09-03 18:03:13.882 701-701/com.feliperrm.babbelproject D/Txt Y: -70.0
09-03 18:03:13.890 701-701/com.feliperrm.babbelproject D/Txt Y: -69.0
09-03 18:03:13.922 701-701/com.feliperrm.babbelproject D/Txt Y: -68.0
09-03 18:03:13.923 701-701/com.feliperrm.babbelproject D/Txt Y: -67.0
09-03 18:03:13.964 701-701/com.feliperrm.babbelproject D/Txt Y: -117.0
09-03 18:03:13.974 701-701/com.feliperrm.babbelproject D/Txt Y: -116.0
09-03 18:03:13.990 701-701/com.feliperrm.babbelproject D/Txt Y: -115.0
09-03 18:03:14.021 701-701/com.feliperrm.babbelproject D/Txt Y: -114.0
09-03 18:03:14.044 701-701/com.feliperrm.babbelproject D/Txt Y: -113.0
09-03 18:03:14.058 701-701/com.feliperrm.babbelproject D/Txt Y: -112.0
```

And this behavious repeats all over (the text view gets to a point and goes back up). What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

Found out the problem, but I'm still curious about why it's happening.
This function I posted above is being called multiple times, therefore while RxJava is making the textView fall, the first line

```
txtFalling.setY(fallingWordStartY);
```

makes it go back up again. But why is the function being called multiple times?
This is the place where I call it:

```
txtCurrentWord.animate().setDuration(1000).setStartDelay(150).alpha(1f).scaleX(1f).scaleY(1f).setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator())
                .setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                        super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
                        txtCurrentWord.animate()
                                .y(topWordY - txtCurrentWord.getHeight()/5)
                                .scaleX(0.6f).scaleY(0.6f).setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator()).setStartDelay(250).setDuration(750).start();
                        bgNewWord.animate().alpha(0f).setStartDelay(250).setDuration(750)
                                .setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                                        super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
                                        bgNewWord.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                        initiateCurrentWordFall();
                                    }
                                }).start();
                    }
                }).start();
```

Sorry about it being very ugly, there are a lot of nested animations, as I only start one after the other ends. Strange that the onAnimationEnd is being called multiple times even though I don't restart them!

Comment: What wrongAnswerOrWordFeel() do?

Comment: Just removes one life from the player, or if the life is already zero it ends the game. Nothing related to the Subscriber or observer.

Comment: It always reset in the -67?

Comment: it always restarts at -117, but on each interaction it reached a higher Y before going back to -117. This is so strange!!

Comment: It looks like multi thread problem. I believe that you have some code running in another thread that are making the txtFalling update and reset to the initial state.

Comment: @jonathanrz I just found out what's happening, will edit the post, see if you can help me!

Answer (score 1):

I just found out my own problem. To those interested, I was starting an animation on a view that had an animation listener set, so even though this listener wasn't set during this animation setup, it still got called, and it was set to call itself over and over again. I just had to add .setListener(null) on the inner txtCurrentWord animation.

Answer (score 0):

I think you were on the right track when you were originally thinking of using RxJava to chain your animations. As a sample, I've written a wrapper that turns an animation into an `Observable`. The observable returns the `View` that is being animated, to facilitate cleaning up. As a bonus, it doesn't use an AnimationListener. The side-effect of this is that you own't get notified if the animation is cancelled, but you can replace `.withEndAction()` with an AnimationListener if you need that. This basic idiom could be used with other animation types as well, such as ObjectAnimators.

```
public class RxAnimation {
    public static Observable<View> wrapViewPropertyAnimation(View view, Func1<View, ViewPropertyAnimator> animationCall) {
        return Observable.<View>create(emitter -> {
            ViewPropertyAnimator animation =
                    animationCall.call(view)
                    .withEndAction(() -> emitter.onNext(view));
            animation.start();
            emitter.setSubscription(new MainThreadSubscription() {
                @Override
                protected void onUnsubscribe() {
                    animation.cancel();
                }
            });
        }, Emitter.BackpressureMode.BUFFER)
                .subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
    }

    public static void initiateCurrentWordFall() {
        // Whatever this does...
    }

    public static void runSampleCode(View txtCurrentWord, View bgNewWord, int topWordY) {
        wrapViewPropertyAnimation(txtCurrentWord, v -> 
                v.animate().setDuration(1000).setStartDelay(150)
                .alpha(1f).scaleX(1f).scaleY(1f)
                .setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator()))
                .switchMap(lastView -> wrapViewPropertyAnimation(lastView, v ->
                        v.animate().y(topWordY - txtCurrentWord.getHeight()/5)
                        .scaleX(0.6f).scaleY(0.6f)
                        .setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator())
                        .setStartDelay(250).setDuration(750)))
                .switchMap(lastView -> wrapViewPropertyAnimation(bgNewWord, v ->
                        v.animate().alpha(0f).setStartDelay(250).setDuration(750))
                )
                .doOnNext(lastView -> {
                    lastView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    initiateCurrentWordFall();
                })
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                // You should make sure your observable is bound to an Activity lifecycle
                // to avoid leaks. I use RxLifecycle for this.
                .subscribe();
    }
}
```